# CSS: best way to have a text aligned on the top of the container div

Tags: html, css

I was wondering, what's the best way to achieve this:

What I want
[image: What I want]

Instead of this, that is the default situation:

[image: Default situation]

How can I align the top of a inline element with the top of it's container? I just saw a lot of answers and methods, and I'm confused. What's the best practice? Until now I just used negative margin, but to me it looks more like a dirty and unstable trick than a clean e reliable solution.

Comment: The JSFiddle for this:
https://jsfiddle.net/Huc91/kr91nq29/

Comment: where is your code? please edit your question by adding the code in the jsfiddle so that other can help you easily

Comment: From the small amount of information given, it could be as simple as removing any top-padding or top-margin from the elements you want to "top-align".

Comment: it's in the first comment. As a Stackoverflow newbie I can't have more than two link in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior you want to 'fix' is because of the way the computer font metrics are calculated. Recently [a very good article](http://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align) on this topic has been published.

You need to get the difference between "ascent" metric and the capital height of your font somehow and then move the text up by this value. Unfortunately, it's impossible with CSS currently, so some hardcoded font-specific 'magic numbers' seem inevitable here.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know!

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on the font how much space there is on top of a normal capital Letter, e.g. to leave space for the dots on top `AAÄAA`

But what works was to reduce the line-height for the first line or the top margin relative (in `em` so it will fit for all font-sizes) to the text size. Just play around with it a little:

```
*::first-line {
    line-height: 0.7em;
}
```

Comment: That's interesting, I created some font in my student career as a graphic designer and I should have thinked about that! It totally makes sense. This solution seems the most smart. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry but I can't upvote you, I'll do it for sure when I have the proper reputation

Answer (score 0):

You need to use position property. Below is the sample code

```
#met {
font-size: 30px;
background-color: green;
float:left;
display:inline-block;
z-index: 1;
}
.na{
  position:relative;
}
.na p,
.na a {
  position:relative;
  top: -5px;
}
a {
 vertical-align:top;
}

#tim {
font-size: 20px;
background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks selvassn, but I already know this. I want to avoid that: "top: -5px;" as well as every negative margin

Answer (score 0):

First part is okay here with  `line-height:21px;` . Couldn't find what worng with p tag even after removing padding and margins

```css
#met {
font-size: 30px;
background-color: green;
float:left;
display:inline-block;

}

a {
 line-height:21px;
 vertical-align:top;
}

#tim {
font-size: 20px;
background-color: blue;
#met {
font-size: 30px;
background-color: green;
float:left;
display:inline-block;

}

a {
 line-height:21px;
 vertical-align:top;
}

#tim {
font-size: 20px;
background-color: blue;
margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

p{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="na" id="met">
  <a>TITLE</a>
</div>
<div class="na" id="tim">
  <p class="dummy">
  Dummy dummy dummy text<br>
    <span id="sp-dum">one two three it's a dummy</span>
  </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Shivkumar, to achieve what you wanna do maybe you should add a negative margin to the p tag and position relative. That's what I alway do but I just wanted to know what was the best solution to this problem, if there was one. And Samuel Kirschner and Ilya Streltsyn actually gave one :-)

Comment: @LucaT. Its fine dear.The most preferred way we all go with margins. but I just want to highlight the line-height property which most people won't take into consideration.

Comment: Thanks for you time Shivkumar

Answer (score 0):

Write in style **vertical-align:top** is good way to display all the content in the top of the line fopr all columns